# How do I include erratum-ibid in a BibTeX entry?

Tags: bibtex

When an error is discovered in a scientific paper, it is customary for the author to write a correction paper, which is then cited together with the original reference using the "erratum-ibid" figure.
What is the "proper" way of using erratum-ibid in a BibTeX entry?
An example reference should look like this:

N. J. Poplawski, Phys. Lett. B694 (2010) 181-185, Erratum-ibid. B701 (2011) 672.

Comment: If they are not in the same issue I think ibid is a wrong term here.

Comment: I would use `addendum` field and use a `\Textcite{...}` to the erratum article

Comment: Christian Hupfer, can you expand a bit on your comment and maybe post it as an answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Biblatex directly supports what you're asking about via the `related` and `relatedstring` fields. An example would be, after modifying [Christian Hupfer's solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/219801/63575), what I have below. You can change `relatedstring` to anything you like. Note that when you just cite `gani-1955`, the bibliography looks like what I've shown below. If you cite both `gani-1955` and `gani-corrigenda-1955`, then you get what's in the picture plus a bibliography entry for `gani-corrigenda-1955` itself (including the author and year info missing from the picture).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-ibid, autocite=footnote]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{myerratum.bib}
@article{gani-1955,
    author  = {Gani, J.},
    title   = {Some Theorems and Sufficiency Conditions for the Maximum-Likelihood Estimator of an Unknown Parameter in a Simple {Markov} Chain},
    journal = {Biometrika},
    date    = {1955-12-01},
    volume  = {42},
    issue   = {3/4},
    pages   = {342--359},
    doi     = {https://doi.org/10.1093/biomet/42.3-4.342},

    related = {gani-corrigenda-1955},
    relatedstring={Corrected in},
}

@article{gani-corrigenda-1955,
    author  = {Gani, J.},
    title   = {Corrigenda},
    journal = {Biometrika},
    date    = {1956-12-01},
    volume  = {43},
    issue   = {3/4},
    pages   = {497--498},
    doi     = {10.1093/biomet/43.3-4.497},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{myerratum.bib}
\begin{document}
\nocite{gani-1955}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

The precise output of `\Textcite` depends on the cite style and of course, on `biblatex`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=alphabetic-verb]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{myerratum.bib}
  @article{wrongarticle,
    author={{S}hakespeare, {W}illiam},
    title={Taming of the shrew},
    journal={POWS},
    year={1600},
    pages={1-10},
    addendum={Erratum-ibid. \Textcite{erratumarticle}},
    }

  @article{erratumarticle,
    author={{S}hakespeare, {W}illiam},
    title={Taming of the shrew -- Erratum},
    journal={POWS -- Addendum},
    year={1601},
    pages={200-205},
  }


\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{myerratum.bib}

\begin{document}

\nocite{wrongarticle}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why does it only work with `\Textcite` for citing the erratum in the reference entry?

Comment: I found out, `\cite` also works for citing the erratum inside the reference entry. You first have to typeset correctly such that all references except the erratum is nicely shown, then do the same procedure again, for the erratum to be actually cited and thus shown. This is true when the erratum is only cited in the reference entry.